# How to parse XHTML node value with TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, xquery

I have the following XHTML and would like to be able to parse out **My Node Value**. Is there a way to easily do this with TSQL?

```
<SPAN style="WHITE-SPACE: normal; WORD-SPACING: 0px; TEXT-TRANSFORM: none; FLOAT: none; COLOR: rgb(0,0,0); TEXT-ALIGN: left; FONT: 10px verdana; DISPLAY: inline !important; LETTER-SPACING: normal; TEXT-INDENT: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px">My Node Value</SPAN>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can extract the node text with XML methods as long as the value is well-formed XML.

If the XHTML value is a parameter or variable:

```
DECLARE @XHTML xml = N'<SPAN style="WHITE-SPACE: normal; WORD-SPACING: 0px; TEXT-TRANSFORM: none; FLOAT: none; COLOR: rgb(0,0,0); TEXT-ALIGN: left; FONT: 10px verdana; DISPLAY: inline !important; LETTER-SPACING: normal; TEXT-INDENT: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px">My Node Value</SPAN>'
SELECT @XHTML.value('.','varchar(100)');
```

If the XHTML value is in a table column:

```
SELECT YourColumn.value('.','varchar(100)')
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

The node paths can be adjusted if the `SPAN` element is not the root node.

Answer (score 3):

**The correct, and more performant, way to retrieve a node's inner text** is to use  the `text()` function.

You also need `[1]` to statically guarantee a single value

```sql
SELECT YourColumn.value('(/SPAN/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```